# Find all points on surface at which the tangent plane is parallel to the plane

Tags: calculus

Similar questions have been asked here before, and I think I understand the subject well, but there must be something wrong with me today as I've been stuck on this problem for a while:

"Find all points on the surface $z = x^3 + xy^2$ at which the tangent plane is parallel to the plane $2x + 2y + z = 0$"

I tried to set the gradient vector $<3x^2 + y^2, 2xy, -1>$ equal to $k<2, 2, 1>$, but can't find a solution. Should I be using a different method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your method seems correct. You can use Wolfram Alpha to visualize them: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%3Dx%5E3%2Bxy%5E2, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%3D-2x-2y

Comment: Hi, I'm not really sure what I should be looking at here... Maybe it's just because I can't move the graphs and I'm bad at 3D-vizualising, haha.

The method is correct but yields no correct answer... Does that mean the answer is "there are no tangent planes parallel to that plane"? Not gonna lie, that's both a relief and frustrating.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is just a tool, not a proof. From the graph you can see that the 2 surfaces "tilt in different directions", which was already proven in your computation.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help!